# Vaadin - Disable Column reordering for particular column

Tags: vaadin, multiple-columns

I'm doing a project in Vaadin 7.

In my project,  I need to disable column reordering feature for particular columns in Treetable?

I'm really searching for function like this 'setColumnReorderIds()'.

Is it possible to do it in Vaadin 7.

Or else I need to write some code with 'ColumnReorderListener()'?

**Update**

This code is to set the first column fixed in a TreeTable. I want to disable reordering in Hierarchy column in the tree table.

```
public class CustomTreeTable extends TreeTable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private Object[] visibleColumns;
private KeyMapper<Object> columnIdMap = new KeyMapper<Object>();

@Override
public void paintContent(PaintTarget target) throws PaintException {
    super.paintContent(target);
    paintColumnOrder(target);
}

private void paintColumnOrder(PaintTarget target) throws PaintException {
    visibleColumns = this.getVisibleColumns();
    final String[] colorder = new String[visibleColumns.length];
    int i = 0;
    colorder[i++] = columnIdMap.key("Column 1"); // Logic to keep the first column fixed
    for (Object colId : visibleColumns) {
        if(!colId.equals("Column 1")) {
            colorder[i++] = columnIdMap.key(colId);
        }
    }
    target.addVariable(this, "columnorder", colorder);
}
}
```

**Update 2**

I tried what Oskar said..

In addition to

```
paintColumnOrder(target).
```

I'm calling

```
paintVisibleColumnOrder(target), 
paintAvailableColumns(target), 
paintVisibleColumns(target).
```

i'm able to stop reordering only for the table headers. But, the body is still reordering. Any guesses on this issue?

Comment: someone please answer this..

Answer (score 1):

In the documentation there is only `setColumnReorderingAllowed()` which allows to control reordering of **all** columns. So if your case is to control particular ones it looks to me as a very custom behaviour and I would go with own implementation. Also `ColumnReorderEvent` is generated **after** processing the action itself therefore implementing own `ColumnReorederListener` won't help us here I think.

All actual magic which we want to change happens in `private Table.paintColumnOrder()` called from `public Table.paintContent()`, called from `public TreeTable.paintContent()` (see sources of [Table](https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin/blob/master/server/src/com/vaadin/ui/Table.java) and [TreeTable](https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin/blob/master/server/src/com/vaadin/ui/TreeTable.java)). The solution would be:

1. extend `TreeTable`
2. override `paintContent()` with merged copies of `Table.paintContent()` and `TreeTable.paintContent()`
3. replace `paintColumnOrder()` call with your custom logic.

**Update**

Ok, now I see it's more tricky then I thought at the beginnig, since there is no easy way to access most of required fields and methods after subclassing TreeTable... Moreover, columns are reorered on the client side and only the change event status is sent to inform the server. I don't know how to handle custom reordering without creating custom gwt widget :(

Comment: Hey Oskar.. Thanks for the idea.. I tried what you said.. but it is not working.. check my updated question.. Correct me where I am wrong..

Comment: Actually I want to disable reordering in Hierarchy column in the tree table.